# Merge multiple (csv) zip file content to single file zipped

Tags: java, scala

I have large(over 200)  number of zipped files. All the files have same structure (csv data). I need to create a single csv file(say total.csv) by appending the content of all the files and zip the final file(total.zip).

Currently I am unzipping every file and appending the content to a text file(total.csv) and finally creating total.zip.

```
I am wondering if there is way to improve the process by appending the zip content ?
```

Btw I am doing this in Java.

Comment: Kind of.  Instead of writing to a `File` stream, you could write directly to the `ZipInputStream` of your zip file...

Comment: yes that is some improvement. I am wondering if there is a way to do this with out extracting the individual part files.

Comment: Well, again, simply pipe the `ZipInputStream` from your part files to the `ZipOutputStream` of your target file ... as an idea

Comment: I can give it a shot but wondering if that would double zip the content ?

Comment: Just don't close the ZipOutputStream until you've processed all the files

Answer (score 0):

based on comments to the question, I decided to provide you some code:

```
import java.io._
import java.util.zip.{ZipEntry, ZipOutputStream, ZipFile}

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object Merger {

  implicit class StringFilePath(path: String) {
    def file = new File(path)
  }

  def merge(zips: Seq[File], out: File) = {
    val outArchive = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(out))
    outArchive.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("merged.csv"))

    zips.foreach({ zip =>
      val inArchive = new ZipFile(zip)

      try inArchive.entries().foreach(entry => {
        val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inArchive.getInputStream(entry)))
        in.lines()
          .iterator()
          .foreach(line => outArchive.write(s"$line\n".getBytes))
        in.close()
      })

      finally {
        inArchive.close()
      }
    })
    outArchive.close()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = merge(Seq("zipcsv.zip".file, "zipcsv1.zip".file), "merged.zip".file)

}
```

Code is in scala, but i think that it is pretty much clear that there is no so much "scalish" code over there, because it is all about working with files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is helpful with a small change. Input is list of zip files. I am still looking for a way to avoid unzipping the input zip files.

Comment: Updated to process input as collection of zip files.